# setTimeout, clearTimeout jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, settimeout

I have an existing function in a content slider script, that sets a timeout for the next slide to animate in. I would like to stop the animation on mouseover (I commented my addition to the script). What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

```
    function autoSlide() {
        if (navClicks == 0 || !settings.autoSlideStopWhenClicked) {
            if (currentPanel == panelCount) {
                var offset = 0;
                currentPanel = 1;
            } else {
                var offset = - (panelWidth*currentPanel);
                currentPanel += 1;
            };
            alterPanelHeight(currentPanel - 1);
            // Switch the current tab:
            slider.siblings('.coda-nav').find('a').removeClass('current').parents('ul').find('li:eq(' + (currentPanel - 1) + ') a').addClass('current');
            // Slide:



            $('.panel-container', slider).animate({ marginLeft: offset }, settings.slideEaseDuration, settings.slideEaseFunction);

            setTimeout(autoSlide,settings.autoSlideInterval); 

     // this is my addition to try to stop the animation:               
            $('.panel-container', slider).mouseover(function(){
            //alert("hi");
               clearTimeout(autoSlide);

            }).mouseleave(function(){

               setTimeout(autoSlide,settings.autoSlideInterval);

            });
    // end of my addition          

        };
    };
```

Comment: You could post [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo if it is still not working (it is easier when you actually see what's going on).

Answer (score 3):

`clearTimeout()` works with the return value of `setTimeout()` (an ID for the operation), so you should save it when you set it, and use that for the clear.

```
var x=setTimeout(autoSlide,settings.autoSlideInterval); 
...
clearTimeout(x);
```

- [MDC on `clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.clearTimeout)

> window.clearTimeout(timeoutID)
>
> where
>   timeoutID is the ID of the timeout you
>   wish to clear, as returned by
>   window.setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

`autoSlide` isn't the timeout, it's your function name so you can't clear the timeout on it.  `setTimeout` returns a reference to the timeout which you need to capture and call `clearTimeout` on that.  See below code:

```
var slideTimeout = setTimeout(autoSlide,settings.autoSlideInterval); 


$('.panel-container', slider).mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout(slideTimeout);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    slideTimeout = setTimeout(autoSlide,settings.autoSlideInterval);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That totally seems to make sense, but :(, it didn't work. And now the slides are sliding in and out really fast. Weird.

Comment: try moving the declaration of slideTimeout outside your function or assign it into the window object: `window.slideTimeout`.  It probably shouldn't be declared inside the function, that's my bad.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried that meself, but it didn't help. Funnily enough, just setting the variable (inside or outside the function), makes the slides go back and forth really quickly. There must be something else not right.